# cannot access ActivityCompatApi23

Tags: android, android-studio

```
C:\Users\pramod pams\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginRegister3\app\src\main\java\com\pramod\loginregister\firstpage.java
Error:(9, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
Error:(12, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(15, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(17, 39) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(18, 38) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(22, 53) error: not an enclosing class: firstpage
Error:(23, 26) error: not an enclosing class: firstpage
Error:(24, 17) error: cannot find symbol method finish()
Error:(30, 54) error: not an enclosing class: firstpage
Error:(31, 26) error: not an enclosing class: firstpage
Error:(32, 17) error: cannot find symbol method finish()
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 20.886 secs
>   Information:13 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Nobody will understand this. Kindly format it of put the screenshot of android studio.

Comment: needs more details...

Answer (score 0):

Library Positive

compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.+'

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.5.8'